# Defining clusters from a matrix using a value threshold and named by cluster size in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, hierarchical-clustering

I have a matrix of pairwise differences between samples. I would like to label each sample as being part of a cluster, named by cluster size, where clusters are defined by an absolute cutoff in the matrix values, e.g. all those clusters with a difference of zero from each other.

Mock data:

```
# Load packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

## Generate fake data
# matrix
d = {'sample_A': [0,2,0,1,1,2,2,1], 'sample_B': [2,0,2,3,3,0,0,3], 'sample_C': [0,2,0,1,1,2,2,1], 'sample_D': [1,3,1,0,2,3,3,1],
     'sample_E': [1,3,1,2,0,3,3,1], 'sample_F': [2,0,2,3,3,0,0,3], 'sample_G': [2,0,2,3,3,0,0,3], 'sample_H': [1,3,1,1,1,3,3,0]}
idx = ["sample_A","sample_B","sample_C","sample_D","sample_E", "sample_F", "sample_G", "sample_H"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,index=idx)
df

# Visualise heatmap (this isn't directly needed for this output)
g = sns.clustermap(df, cmap="coolwarm_r")
g

# Desired output
d = {'cluster_zero': [2,1,2,"NA","NA",1,1,"NA"]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d,index=idx)
df3
```

So the output labels each sample as belonging to a cluster defined as having zero pairwise difference in the matrix, and names the cluster in order of size from largest to smallest. In this case, samples B, F and G all have zero differences, so get put in cluster 1. Samples A and C also have zero differences from each other, and as that cluster is smaller than B/F/G they are cluster 2. There are no other samples with zero differences in this case, so the other samples don't get a cluster.

Ideally, I would like to be able to control the threshold of difference I used to define clusters, e.g. run the script again but using a threshold of <1 or <2 rather than zero.

There are various questions similar to this (e.g. [Extracting clusters from seaborn clustermap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924813/extracting-clusters-from-seaborn-clustermap)), but they seem to use metrics of calculating distance rather than the absolute count in the matrix. Another similar question is: [generating numerical clusters from matrix values of a minimal size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738648/generating-numerical-clusters-from-matrix-values-of-a-minimal-size) but this counts the size of each cluster, which is different to the output I want.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question in this blog:
https://joernhees.de/blog/2015/08/26/scipy-hierarchical-clustering-and-dendrogram-tutorial/

The solution I've done is:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_arr = np.asarray(df)

Z = hierarchy.linkage(df_arr, 'single')
plt.figure()
dn = hierarchy.dendrogram(Z)

from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fcluster

# Set maximum threshold for difference e.g. 1
max_d = 1
clusters = fcluster(Z, max_d, criterion='distance')
clusters
```

Then I turn the clusters array into a dataframe and pd.concat it onto the distances dataframe, then extract the list of sample names with cluster. Lastlt I take only clusters with e.g. >2 samples in each cluster:

```
result = result.groupby('cluster').filter(lambda x : len(x)>2)
```